# Target class element instead of document body with flickering animation script

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, effect

I've found this script on the world wide web ;) It's great for what I need, now only thing is I want to target a single css class element (let's say .blink) How can I modify this to work? Think I'm overlooking something small because I'm not getting it to work.

```
function lightning()
{flash=flash+1;
if(flash==1){document.bgColor='white'; setTimeout("lightning()",100);}
if(flash==2){document.bgColor='black'; setTimeout("lightning()",90);}
if(flash==3){document.bgColor='red'; setTimeout("lightning()",85);}
if(flash==4){document.bgColor='blue'; setTimeout("lightning()",80);}
if(flash==5){document.bgColor='purple'; setTimeout("lightning()",75);}
if(flash==6){document.bgColor='white'; setTimeout("lightning()",70);}
if(flash==7){document.bgColor='black'; setTimeout("lightning()",65);}
if(flash==8){document.bgColor='red'; setTimeout("lightning()",60);}
if(flash==9){document.bgColor='blue'; setTimeout("lightning()",50);}
if(flash==10){document.bgColor='purple'; setTimeout("lightning()",40);}
if(flash==11){document.bgColor='black'; setTimeout("lightning()",30);}
if(flash==12){document.bgColor='white'; setTimeout("lightning()",25);}
if(flash==13){document.bgColor='red'; setTimeout("lightning()",20);}
if(flash==14){document.bgColor='blue'; setTimeout("lightning()",10);}
if(flash==15){document.bgColor='purple'; setTimeout("lightning()",5);}
if(flash==16){document.bgColor='white'; setTimeout("lightning()",1);}
if(flash==17){document.bgColor='black'; setTimeout("lightning()",1);}
if(flash==18){document.bgColor='blue'; setTimeout("lightning()",1);}
if(flash==19){document.bgColor='purple'; setTimeout("lightning()",1);}
if(flash==20){flash=0; setTimeout("lightning()",100);}
}
setTimeout("lightning()",1);
```

Thanks, hope to hear form you guys! And btw maybe someone has a better/shorter script with similar effect ;)

Comment: [maybe this?](https://jsfiddle.net/xahc5wom/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to query the class you want to blink and iterate through each element. I also changed to a switch statement instead of an if statement and did some formatting and changed so that `flash` isn't a global variable.

```js
function lightning(className, flash = 1) {
  const flashes = {
    1: { color: "white", delay: 100 },
    2: { color: "black", delay: 90 },
    3: { color: "red", delay: 85 },
    4: { color: "blue", delay: 80 },
    5: { color: "purple", delay: 75 },
    6: { color: "white", delay: 70 },
    7: { color: "black", delay: 65 },
    8: { color: "red", delay: 60 },
    9: { color: "blue", delay: 50 },
    10: { color: "purple", delay: 40 },
    11: { color: "black", delay: 30 },
    12: { color: "white", delay: 25 },
    13: { color: "red", delay: 20 },
    14: { color: "blue", delay: 10 },
    15: { color: "purple", delay: 5 },
    16: { color: "white", delay: 1 },
    17: { color: "black", delay: 1 },
    18: { color: "blue", delay: 1 },
    19: { color: "purple", delay: 1 }
  };

  switch (flash) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
    case 11:
    case 12:
    case 13:
    case 14:
    case 15:
    case 16:
    case 17:
    case 18:
    case 19:
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(className)).forEach(
        el => (el.style.backgroundColor = flashes[flash].color)
      );
      setTimeout(() => lightning(className, flash + 1), flashes[flash].delay);
    case 20:
      setTimeout(() => lightning(className), 100);
  }
}
setTimeout(() => lightning("my-class-name"), 1);
```

**Update**: simpler code that does almost the same thing (the delays/colors are not 100% the same as in your original code):

```js
function lightning(className, flash = 1) {
  const color = i => {
    switch (i % 5) {
      case 1:
        return "white";
      case 2:
        return "red";
      case 3:
        return "blue";
      case 4:
        return "purple";
      case 0:
        return "black";
    }
  };

  if (flash > 0 && flash < 20) {
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(className)).forEach(
      el => (el.style.backgroundColor = color(flash))
    );
    setTimeout(() => lightning(className, flash + 1), 100 - flash * 5);
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => lightning(className), 100);
  }
}

setTimeout(() => lightning("my-class-name"), 1);
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm ;) Thanks for the shorter code, looks very clean! If you wanne see the page https://www.joinforjoy.net/eureka/ (it's for a charity fund raising campaign, still working on this).

Comment: Great, you're welcome! Just don't give someone a epileptic seizure with that thing  Hope you raise a lot of money!